# Mod Wordpress Template...Which One?

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone here knows which file I can modify to change the date divs in wordpress? If you should look at my site: www.xternalit.co.uk, I want to chage the date to my personal image. No image will be the same.

Chers!

Answer (score 0):

Not a file but just date settings in the admin console, under options section

Comment: Ok. but I want to remove the date on the left and place my image there. Different images for every topic. hope u understand.